# Loading 32 bit COM dll in a 64-bit office addin

Tags: c#, excel, com, ms-office, 32bit-64bit

I want to achieve one thing. I want to use 32 bit COM type library from an Excel Add in. Note that 64-bit excel 2010 is installed on my machine. I have compiled the add in in 32 bits. But when i create instance of a COM class, it gives this error 
    "retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error Class not registered"
Is it possible what I am trying to do ? Any suggestions (except using another version of Excel or 1 64 bit COM type library) ?

Comment: This might help: http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Comment: Have you registered your COM component ?

Comment: Registered? Yes I think i have. I added it by right click Reference > Add reference > COM > MyCOMComponent !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked like a charm 
gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment

Comment: I was trying to figure out this same problem.! Having some doubts on this.

Comment: I remember we did not use the solution because it did not suit our software application in a wider context

Comment: so whats the solution for making 32bit office dll to work in 64bit office

Comment: We re-wrote our add In in 64-bit. But you can try the solution posted above , it works!

Comment: ya that is wat i needed,How to write 64bit office addin.??

Comment: I am sorry, as far as I remember, We modified the existing add in such that it was compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit Office.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831%28v=office.14%29.aspx